# C# - SendKeys Access is denied when windows is locked

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I'm testing an application that remotes another app via `SendKeys` every things works fine when the windows is logged on. Here is the test code for notepad (notepad is open):

```
Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Last();
if (p != null)
{
  IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
  SetForegroundWindow(h);
  SendKeys.SendWait("Hellow world");
}
```

I expect it work when the windows is locked, but the error is 'Access is denied'. Notepad is the test app and locking system is the simulation of disconnecting Remote Desktop, so I have to access in locked mode. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because when windows are locked the accessibility to desktop is locked, now desktop cannot receive input. Focus to desktop is lost.  GET/SETForegroundWindow, will not work.

I did not tried it but

```
OpenDesktop(
  _In_ LPTSTR      lpszDesktop,
  _In_ DWORD       dwFlags,
  _In_ BOOL        fInherit,
  _In_ ACCESS_MASK dwDesiredAccess
)
```

This function may help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684303(v=vs.85).aspx